# Should I use "would notice" or "would have noticed" in the following case?

Tags: grammar, tense, past-tense, conditional-constructions, perfect-constructions

> Mary expected the foundation to be a mansion. Instead, she met such a
>   ordinary apartment no one would (have) noticed if a demolition company
>   destroyed it and drove it away in trucks.

This excerpt is written in past-tense narrative. Should it be "would notice" or "would have noticed"? And why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last part of the sentence is a condition ("if a demolition company..."). That condition did not happen; it is *counterfactual*, and it refers to a past time frame.

In this type of conditional statement (called the [third conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Third_conditional)), the condition should be in **past perfect** and counterfactual result is stated with "have", as in present perfect (this is called [Conditional Perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_perfect)). So the sentence should better be

> (...) no one would *have* noticed if a demolition company *had* destroyed it and drove it away in trucks.

The quoted sentence, with past simple instead of past perfect in the condition, is of the [second conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Second_conditional) type, which refers to a counterfactual condition at the **present** time frame. In this case it would still be understood correctly from the context, but the third conditional is a better choice.